# Geany syntax highlighting questions

Tags: templates, scala, text-editor

1) Are there any Geany users here who have gotten good syntax highlighting for Scala?

2) What should I do about syntax highlighting when I'm editing (Mako) templates that are generating things other than HTML/CSS/JS? (say, C/C++ code, or w/e)  Is good syntax highlighting too much to ask out of Geany in this case (or any other editor, for that matter)?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to chime in to note that the latest version of geany (1.22) does have syntax highlighting for Scala - it's rudimentary, but it will at least highlight comments and a few keywords. Annoyingly, the support is initially only activated for files named `Foo.scl`, rather than using the standard convention of `Foo.scala`, but this can be changed by modifying `/usr/share/geany/filetype_extensions.conf` (the format is pretty obvious).